# Issue with parsing Date string

Tags: java, android, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse the following string to a `Date` object:

```
2013-12-26T01:00:56.664Z
```

Using this `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

But I'm getting a:

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-12-26T01:00:56.664Z" (at offset 19)
```

What am I doing wrong, How I should handle the `T` and the `Z` letters in the date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real isssue with the date is not T & Z but the milliseconds.

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` This must be the format that is to be used becaue there are milli seconds as well in the input date.

Comment: Your answer was the first correct answer, so Thank you very much : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
String date = "2013-12-26T01:00:56.664Z";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
try {
   System.out.println(sdf.parse(date)); // Result Thu Dec 26 01:00:56 CET 2013
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```